# php check for duplicates and count the number of occurrences in the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For a given array of number I need to print the duplicates along with the number of time they occurred in the array in the key value pair or associative array.

Given Array

```
$arr = [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,8,9,10,2,5,9,10,10];
```

Desired result

```
Array
(
    [2] => 4
    [5] => 4
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 3
)
```

What I have tried:

```
$arr = [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,8,9,10,2,5,9,10,10];
sort($arr);

$duplicates = [];
$count = 1; // I assumed that at least one element is always there so I did not take 0 (if I am not wrong)

for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){  
  for($j = $i+1; $j<count($arr); $j++){
    if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]){  
      if(!in_array($arr[$j], $duplicates)){
        // array_push($duplicates, $arr[$j]);
        $count++;
        $duplicates[$arr[$j]] = $count;
      }
    }else{
      $count = 1;
    }
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($duplicates);
```

This successfully returns the duplicates as `key` but number of occurrences are incorrect.

Current Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 4
)
```

What mistake am I making? Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Its too bad that the interviewer wants the most complicated method, here is a simple one liner: $dupes = array_filter(array_count_values($array), function($v) { return $v > 1; });

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the time complexity of your solution, it's not very efficient apart from logical error. Here is a solution that works:

```
<?php
function solution($arr) {
    $result =   array();
    $i = 0;
    /* Increase count for each numbers */
    while( $i < count($arr) ) {
        $current = $arr[$i];
        if ( !array_key_exists("$current", $result) ) {
            $result["$current"] = 1;
        } else {
            $result["$current"] += 1;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    /* Remove values less than 2 */
    foreach ( $result as $k => $res ) {
        if ( $res < 2 ) {
            unset($result[$k]);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}

solution([1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,8,9,10,2,5,9,10,10]);
?>
```

> Output:

```
{"2":4,"5":4,"9":2,"10":3}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. That looks like a good solution. But, let's consider that I want to stick to my code even if the time complexity is not efficient because of using the two iterations. So, taking my code how do I fix it to get the required result? I need to learn that too. The reason is, I received this question in an interview today and the interviewer wanted me to use the `i,j` iterations. The solution you gave is something I knew already and I was aware of the inefficient time complexity of using two iterations. But he wanted to test my logic with iterations. So, how do I fix it ?

Comment: You can keep the current solution and give a new solution with my code below it. Let's give the future readers both the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer isset() instead of array_key_exists() (as suggested by babak-maziar).

```
$arr = [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,8,9,10,2,5,9,10,10];

foreach($arr as $i)
    isset($counters[$i])
        ? $counters[$i]++
        : $counters[$i] = 1;

var_export($counters);
```

output:

```
array (
  1 => 1,
  2 => 4,
  4 => 1,
  5 => 4,
  8 => 1,
  9 => 2,
  10 => 3,
)%
```

Comment: PSR-12 coding standards prefers the use of curly braces.